# Convert OWL/XML in RDF/XML with a simple command line in shell

Tags: java, shell, rdf, owl, owl-api

I'm asking your help to create a converter to transform OWL/XML into RDF/XML. My purpose is to use OWLapi 2 through a simple shell command with bash.
My files are in OWL/XML but I have to transform them into RDF/XML to send them in my fuseki database. I could transform each file thanks to Protégé or a converter available online, but I've more than one thousand files to convert.

See my current java file (but I don't know how to use it) :

```
package owl2rdf;

import java.io.File;
import org.semanticweb.owlapi.apibinding.OWLManager;
import org.semanticweb.owlapi.io.RDFXMLOntologyFormat;
import org.semanticweb.owlapi.model.IRI;
import org.semanticweb.owlapi.model.OWLOntology;
import org.semanticweb.owlapi.model.OWLOntologyManager;

@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
public class owl2rdf {

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    // Get hold of an ontology manager
    OWLOntologyManager manager = OWLManager.createOWLOntologyManager();

    // Load the ontology from a local files
    File file = new File(args[0]);
    System.out.println("Loaded ontology: " + file);
    OWLOntology ontology = manager.loadOntologyFromOntologyDocument(file);

    // Get the ontology format ; in our case it's normally OWL/XML
    OWLOntologyFormat format = manager.OWLOntologyFormat(file);
    System.out.println("    format: " + format);

    // save the file into RDF/XML format
    RDFXMLOntologyFormat rdfxmlFormat = new RDFXMLOntologyFormat();
    manager.saveOntology(ontology, rdfxmlFormat, IRI.create(file));
    }
}
```

When I execute this code, I've many errors relative to exceptions I don't understand at all, but I saw it's a common error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/inject/Provider
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.inject.Provider
```

Comment: Can you just receive a path through input? The code works like a charm, you just need to provide the file link. I don't see the problem. Can you elaborate?

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Thanks to realpath in bash and a main() function in my java code I send the path to the jar:
`r=$(realpath "$i");java -jar owl2rdf.jar "$r"`
But the problem is I don't find rdf ontolongy manager in the java class in the OWLapi, so I have kind of next errors:
`getOntologyFormat(OWLOntology) in the type OWLOntologyManager is not applicable for the arguments (File)`
`saveOntology(OWLOntology, OWLDocumentFormat, IRI) in the type OWLOntologyManager is not applicable for the arguments (File, RDFXMLOntologyFormat, IRI)`

Comment: I resolve my problem with my ontology manager. It was just that the OWLOntology wasn't an ontology object.
But I have now many errors with exceptions I don't really understand. I edit my first message to explain.

Comment: Does the code work without calling it from the command line? I mean can you just test the code to convert one ontology and run it alone?

Comment: I resolve many problems !! I finally understand how to use the maven repository. But I have a problem with an not found class: `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/openrdf/rio/RDFFormat`. But the problem is I have installed the **org.openrdf.rio** package which provide normally the class org.openrdf.rio.rdfformat [see link](http://rdf4j.org/sesame/2.8/apidocs/org/openrdf/rio/class-use/RDFFormat.html).

Comment: The problem is resolved. It was just a problem of dependencies I solved by using maven repository and by downloading last sesame recent api.

Everything works like a charm as you said.

Comment: It is good if you answer your own question and accept the answer so that others can benefit later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To change a entire repository of an OWL/XML file into RDF/XML file:

1- create your package owl2rdf.java

```
package owl2rdf;

//import all necessary classes
import java.io.File;
import org.semanticweb.owlapi.apibinding.OWLManager;
import org.semanticweb.owlapi.io.RDFXMLOntologyFormat;
import org.semanticweb.owlapi.model.IRI;
import org.semanticweb.owlapi.model.OWLOntology;
import org.semanticweb.owlapi.model.OWLOntologyManager;

@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
public class owl2rdf {

#create a main() function to take an argument; here in the example one argument only
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        // Get hold of an ontology manager
        OWLOntologyManager manager = OWLManager.createOWLOntologyManager();

        // Load the ontology from a local files
        File file = new File(args[0]);
        System.out.println("Loaded ontology: " + file);
        OWLOntology ontology = manager.loadOntologyFromOntologyDocument(file);

        // save the file into RDF/XML format
        //in this case, my ontology file and format already manage prefix
        RDFXMLOntologyFormat rdfxmlFormat = new RDFXMLOntologyFormat();
        manager.saveOntology(ontology, rdfxmlFormat, IRI.create(file));
    }
}
```

2- Thanks to a Java-IDE such as Eclipse or something else, manages all dependencies (repo Maven, downloads jar, classplath, etc.)

3- create your bash scrip my-scrip.sh; here absolutely not optimized

```
#!/bin/bash
cd your-dir
for i in *
do
#get the absolute path; be careful, realpath comes with the latest coreutils package
    r=$(realpath "$i")
    #to be not disturb by relative path with java -jar, I put the .jar in the parent directory
    cd ..
    java -jar owl2rdf.jar "$r"
    cd your-dir
done
echo "Conversion finished, see below if there are errors."
```

4- Execute your script
`$ chmod +x my-script.sh;./my-script`

5- haha moment: all your OWL/XML are converted in RDF/XML. You can for example, import them into fuseki or sesame database.

Comment: It works very well !! But it's very slow and clearly not optimized to convert OWL/XML into RDF/XML: 500 ko file spends 4 second to be converted, imagine when you've 1Go or more in your repository.
I think Xslt method could be more efficient but take a lot of time to design.
If you have the possibility to directly write your ontology files in RDF/XML, do it. But it's clear that OWL/XML is easier to manipulate with Xslt and more human readable without complex prefix and namespace everywhere.